# Sensor data trains dataset

Tags: data-request, transportation, time-series, csv, sensors

For an experiment I'm looking for a particular type of data set, been looking for quite a while but couldn't find any data sets which even remotely match this description. Are there any good datasets on the internet with these characteristics:

- time series
- sensor data (temperature, humidity, velocity, frequency, ...)
- collected on trains (or comparable vehicle)
- available in tabular format, like CSV, XSLX, ...
  (or as long as I can convert it to a tabular form and use it locally it should be okay.)

The purpose of this is to emulate a bunch of sensors with real world values. Based on the data, I could let a 'sensor' output a value at a particular rate, for example 20 Hz. This data preferably comes from trains because I need to emulate train sensors, and I don't have access to a real train.

Comment: Is tabular format really important? What if you could get the data from an SOS service as XML

Comment: @nmtoken well as long as i can convert it to a tabular form and use it locally it should be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if [this dataset](http://data.deutschebahn.com/dataset/data-sensordaten-schenker-seefrachtcontainer) matches your requirements completely. At least it reads as a dataset from a German logistics company having sensors mounted on shipping containers. The description is in German but the field names of the dataset are mainly in English.

It contains lat/ lon coordinates, motion, humidity and temperature values. And it comes in csv format already.

Comment: Well it's closer to what I'm looking for than most things I already found myself. With a bit of cleaning and modifications it will be useful to me :) Thank you!